# Mostrar imagen segun variable mayor o menor que

Tags: php

Hola amigos me explico, 
Realizo una consulta para obtener las puntuaciones cuando un usuario en 4 etapas debe adquirir una numeración mayor a 69 puntos, la idea es mostrar una imagen según la puntuación sea mayor o menor que 69 puntos.

Si el usuario no logra los 69 puntos en la primera etapa, se muestra una imagen

```
$comp='<img src="img/icons/alert_graduate.gif" alt="">';
```

esta misma  imagen se debe seguir mostrando si aun en la cuarta etapa este usuario no logro obtener una puntuación mayor a los 69 puntos

cuando el usuario logra esta puntuación no importa su etapa se muestra la imagen

```
$comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">';
```

**codigo:**

```
if ($etapa1 > 69) {
   $comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">';
} elseif ($etapa2 > $etapa1) {
    $comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">';
} elseif ($etapa3 > $etapa1) {
 $comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">';

} elseif ($etapa4 > $etapa1) {
$comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">';

} else{

    $comp='<img src="img/icons/alert_graduate.gif" alt="">';
}
```

Comment: _pero no logro mostrar la imagen aunque si están las puntuaciones_ ¿O sea, el problema son las imágenes?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano  el problema no son las imágenes ya que si solo utilizo la primera etapa me las muestra

Comment: Bueno... dices que las puntuaciones están, y el problema no son las imágenes. Entonces ¿cuál es el problema? Yo hice una prueba con `etapa1=70, etapa2=40, etapa3=30, etapa4=20` y entra en el primer bucle. Si cambio el valor de `etapa1=69` entra en el último bucle. No entiendo cuál es el problema. Por lo demás, casi todas las imágenes son iguales en el código, excepto la última.

Comment: No se entiende bien. Sería bueno que expliques si las puntuaciones entre etapas son acumulativas o no. Si no son acumulativas solamente tienes que comparar si la puntuación de cada etapa `>  69` y lo puedes hacer en un sólo bloque, usando `OR`: `if ($etapa1 > 69 || $etapa2 > 69 || $etapa3 > 69 || $etapa4 > 69) { graduated } else { alert graduate }`

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano es exactamente lo que ando buscando, anteriormente tuve un error debi declarar una variable en mi consulta, por eso no me mostraba nada pero luego de ponerla me lanzo las imagenes, pero incorrectas, ya que revisando directamente en base de datos algunos de estos usuarios en sus etapas tenia 0 y otros en la primera etapa se encuentran vacíos por lo que puede generar un dato incorrecto por lo que tu sugerencia va de la mano

Comment: @A.Cedano si puedes por favor describirme con claridad el codigo ya que deseo utilizar estas dos imagenes, como tendria que ubicarlas usando:  if ($etapa1 > 69 || $etapa2 > 69 || $etapa3 > 69 || $etapa4 > 69) { graduated } else { alert graduate }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te coloco dos códigos, en uno se evalúa si es mayor o igual a 69, en otro, sólo si es mayor a 69. Si el usuario se gradúa con 69 o más puntos, deberías usar el primero, pero si se gradúa con 70 o más puntos, deberías usar el segundo.

**[`Ver Demo del Código`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a308-xays)**

```
   <?php

    $etapa1=69;
    $etapa2=40;
    $etapa3=30;
    $etapa4=20;


    //1ª posibilidad: Evaluando igual o  mayor a 69
    if ($etapa1 >= 69 || $etapa2 >= 69 || $etapa3 >= 69 || $etapa4 >= 69) 
    {
        $comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">'; //Graduado


    } else{

        $comp='<img src="img/icons/alert_graduate.gif" alt="">'; //No graduado
    }
       echo  $comp; 


    //2ª posibilidad: Evaluando  mayor a 69


    if ($etapa1 > 69 || $etapa2 > 69 || $etapa3 > 69 || $etapa4 > 69) 
    {
        $comp='<img src="img/icons/graduate.png" alt="">'; //Graduado


    } else{

        $comp='<img src="img/icons/alert_graduate.gif" alt="">'; //No graduado
    }
       echo  "<br>".$comp; 

    ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias @A.Cedano , me resolvió excelente solo un detalle , coloque el código pero en una consulta que realizo uno de los usuarios contiene lo siguiente etapa1=60 ,. etapa2=61 y en la etapa3=70 , deberia de mostrarme la imagen de graduado pero me mantiene la imagen de alert_graduate ,

Comment: Debe ser que hay un error en la variable de la etapa3. Quizá sea un `70espacio` o un `espacio70` o algo así. Para más seguridad, lo puedes convertir a entero, por ejemplo: `$etapa3=intval($etapa3);` antes de pasarlo al if.

Comment: Muchas Gracias hermano! @A.Cedano

Comment: De nada, me alegro que lo hayas resuelto @AlexanderQuiroz